# Remove focus from/reset ListBox with MultiSelect via jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, listbox

Below is the list box I'm using in my view to allow the user multi-select capability.

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.searchChannelCode, new MultiSelectList(Model.ChannelCodes, "Text", "Value"))
```

I have a jQuery function I use to clear all input fields and I want it to be able to remove the focus from any selected items in the `ListBox`. Thought this would be pretty simple but the jQuery I have below (my first couple attempts) doesn't work. Anyone know how to clear the focus on a `ListBox`?

```
        $("#searchChannelCode").removeAttr("selected");
        $("#searchChannelCode option[value='']").attr('selected', false);
```

For good measure here's the rendered HTML

```
<select id="searchChannelCode" multiple="multiple" name="searchChannelCode">
<option value="G">G</option>
<option value="H">H</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="K">K</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably posted too quick. Answered my own question within minutes.

```
$("#searchChannelCode").find("option").attr("selected", false);
```